# Can't select quota to edit on Google cloud quota edition screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can't check any checkbox on quotas table to edit. I've tried on Firefox and Chrome. I need to edit the "GPUs (all regions)" quota to add 1 gpu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't ask for quota changes while you are on a trial account. You need to activate/upgrade your account to premium. After that, make sure you have an owner role to your project as Nicholas suggested.

After that, go to the Quotas page and select a row in the table. You should be able to select the little box on the right hand side of the screen the selected quota. Then click EDIT QUOTAS on the top of the screen. It will then request a quota increase which will be sent to Google Cloud Support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the appropriate permissions? To change your quotas, you must have serviceusage.quotas.update permission. This permission is included by default for predefined roles: Owner, Editor, and Quota Administrator. Adding one of these to your user should help.

Comment: I have the owner role. Yet I cannot edit it. likely due to my project being under an organization.