# Inability to Edit Quota for "custom_model_training_cpus" Metric

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm facing a problem editing the quota for the "custom_model_training_cpus" metric in AI Platform. Despite being a Full Account with Pay-as-You-Go, remaining credits (€49 out of €373) and an expiration date of 27 September 2023, I'm unable to modify the quota.

During the training pipeline, I receive the following error message:
"Training pipeline failed with error message: The following quota metrics exceed quota limits: aiplatform.googleapis.com/custom_model_training_cpus."

I've checked the documentation and explored my account settings without finding a solution. I'm unsure why I can't edit the quota for this metric.

Any guidance or assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are missing required permission you can view the details [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota_detail/permissions).

> - resourcemanager.projects.get
> - resourcemanager.folders.get (if you want to view quota for an entire Folder)
> - resourcemanager.organizations.get (if you want to view quota for an entire Organization)
> - monitoring.timeSeries.list
> - serviceusage.services.list
> - serviceusage.quotas.get

Also additionally you can check this documentation for more details about Quota limits: https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#types_of_quota

SO reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118854/19378826